# Issues with DIVs and hover effect

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been working on a sub menu for when I hover over main menu items. I have been trying to figure out a different way to display the same effect without the issues when moving my mouse slowly to the sub menu from the main menu items. (You will see the sub menu disappears.) Below is the jsFiddle. Any help would be much appreciated.

NOTE: It does appear slightly different on the jsFiddle as apposed to my website design, but that is irrelevant.

```css
.header {
 height: auto;
 width: 70vw;
 
 display: inline-block;
 
 background-color: #222;
  
 color: #fff;
 
 padding-top: 15px;
 padding-bottom: 75px;
 
 border-top-left-radius: 10px;
 border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}
.menu {
 height: auto;
 width: 100%;
 
 top: 0px;
 
 text-align: center;
 
 display: table;
 table-layout: fixed;
 
 background-color: transparent;
 
 border: thin solid transparent;
 
 border-spacing: 0px;
 border-collapse: collapse;
}
.menu-item {
 font-size: 14px;
 font-family: poppins;
  
 color: #9e9e9e;
 
 padding-top: 20px;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
 
 height: auto;
 width: auto;
 
 background-color: transparent;
 
 display: table-cell;
 
    text-align: center;
 
 cursor: pointer;
 
 text-decoration: none;
}
.menu-item:hover {
 color: #fff;
 background-color: #ff6e00;
}
.menu div {
 border-right: solid thin #333;
 border-left: solid thin #333;
}
.menu div:last-child {
 border-right: none;
}
.menu div:first-child {
 border-left: none;
}



.sub-menu {
 height: auto;
 width: 100%;
 
 display: table;
 table-layout: fixed;
 
 border-spacing: 0px;
 border-collapse: collapse;
}
.sub-menu-item {
 display: table-cell;
 
 height: auto;
 width: auto;
 
 font-size: 14px;
 font-family: raleway;
 
 color: #999;
 background-color: #333;
 
 padding-top: 20px;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
 
 cursor: pointer;
}
.sub-menu-item:hover {
 color: #fff;
 background-color: #666;
}
.sub-menu-item-icon {
 height: auto;
 width: auto;
 
 padding-bottom: 20px;
 
 text-align: center;
 
 vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
 
  <div class="menu">
     
     <div class="menu-item" onMouseOver="document.getElementById('sub-home').style.display = 'table';"  onMouseOut="document.getElementById('sub-home').style.display = 'none';">Home</div>
        
        <div class="menu-item" onMouseOver="document.getElementById('sub-pricing').style.display = 'table';"  onMouseOut="document.getElementById('sub-pricing').style.display = 'none';">Plans &amp; Pricing</div>
        <div class="menu-item">Testimonials</div>
        <div class="menu-item">Design Hub</div>
        <div class="menu-item">Contact Us</div>
     
    </div>
    
    <div class="sub-menu" id="sub-home" onMouseOver="document.getElementById('sub-home').style.display ='table';" onMouseOut="document.getElementById('sub-home').style.display = 'none';">
     
     <div class="sub-menu-item">About Us</div>
        <div class="sub-menu-item">Our Mission</div>
        
    </div>
    
    <div class="sub-menu" id="sub-pricing" onMouseOver="document.getElementById('sub-pricing').style.display = 'table';" onMouseOut="document.getElementById('sub-pricing').style.display = 'none';">
     
     <div class="sub-menu-item"><div class="sub-menu-item-icon"><img src="file:///C|/Users/jesse/Desktop/sight.png" width="100" height="100" alt=""/></div>Website Hosting</div>
        <div class="sub-menu-item"><div class="sub-menu-item-icon"><img src="file:///C|/Users/jesse/Desktop/sight.png" width="100" height="100" alt=""/></div>Email Hosting</div>
        <div class="sub-menu-item"><div class="sub-menu-item-icon"><img src="file:///C|/Users/jesse/Desktop/sight.png" width="100" height="100" alt=""/></div>Domain Names</div>
        <div class="sub-menu-item"><div class="sub-menu-item-icon"><img src="file:///C|/Users/jesse/Desktop/sight.png" width="100" height="100" alt=""/></div>Other Services</div>
        
    </div>
    
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/oqjwvv8m/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

REMOVE THE BORDER ON YOUR `.menu`

```css
.header {
 height: auto;
 width: 70vw;
 
 display: inline-block;
 
 background-color: #222;
  
 color: #fff;
 
 padding-top: 15px;
 padding-bottom: 75px;
 
 border-top-left-radius: 10px;
 border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}
.menu {
 height: auto;
 width: 100%;
 
 top: 0px;
 
 text-align: center;
 
 display: table;
 table-layout: fixed;
 
 background-color: transparent;
 
   
 
 border-spacing: 0px;
 border-collapse: collapse;
}
.menu-item {
 font-size: 14px;
 font-family: poppins;
  
 color: #9e9e9e;
 
 padding-top: 20px;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
 
 height: auto;
 width: auto;
 
 background-color: transparent;
 
 display: table-cell;
 
    text-align: center;
 
 cursor: pointer;
 
 text-decoration: none;
}
.menu-item:hover {
 color: #fff;
 background-color: #ff6e00;
}
.menu div {
 border-right: solid thin #333;
 border-left: solid thin #333;
}
.menu div:last-child {
 border-right: none;
}
.menu div:first-child {
 border-left: none;
}



.sub-menu {
 height: auto;
 width: 100%;
 display: table;
 table-layout: fixed;
 border-spacing: 0px;
 border-collapse: collapse;
}
.sub-menu-item {
 display: table-cell;
 
 height: auto;
 width: auto;
 
 font-size: 14px;
 font-family: raleway;
 
 color: #999;
 background-color: #333;
 
 padding-top: 20px;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
 
 cursor: pointer;
}
.sub-menu-item:hover {
 color: #fff;
 background-color: #666;
}
.sub-menu-item-icon {
 height: auto;
 width: auto;
 
 padding-bottom: 20px;
 
 text-align: center;
 
 vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
 
  <div class="menu">
     
     <div class="menu-item" onMouseOver="document.getElementById('sub-home').style.display = 'table';"  onMouseOut="document.getElementById('sub-home').style.display = 'none';">Home</div>
        
        <div class="menu-item" onMouseOver="document.getElementById('sub-pricing').style.display = 'table';"  onMouseOut="document.getElementById('sub-pricing').style.display = 'none';">Plans &amp; Pricing</div>
        <div class="menu-item">Testimonials</div>
        <div class="menu-item">Design Hub</div>
        <div class="menu-item">Contact Us</div>
     
    </div>
    
    <div class="sub-menu" id="sub-home" onMouseOver="document.getElementById('sub-home').style.display ='table';" onMouseOut="document.getElementById('sub-home').style.display = 'none';">
     
     <div class="sub-menu-item">About Us</div>
        <div class="sub-menu-item">Our Mission</div>
        
    </div>
    
    <div class="sub-menu" id="sub-pricing" onMouseOver="document.getElementById('sub-pricing').style.display = 'table';" onMouseOut="document.getElementById('sub-pricing').style.display = 'none';">
     
     <div class="sub-menu-item"><div class="sub-menu-item-icon"><img src="file:///C|/Users/jesse/Desktop/sight.png" width="100" height="100" alt=""/></div>Website Hosting</div>
        <div class="sub-menu-item"><div class="sub-menu-item-icon"><img src="file:///C|/Users/jesse/Desktop/sight.png" width="100" height="100" alt=""/></div>Email Hosting</div>
        <div class="sub-menu-item"><div class="sub-menu-item-icon"><img src="file:///C|/Users/jesse/Desktop/sight.png" width="100" height="100" alt=""/></div>Domain Names</div>
        <div class="sub-menu-item"><div class="sub-menu-item-icon"><img src="file:///C|/Users/jesse/Desktop/sight.png" width="100" height="100" alt=""/></div>Other Services</div>
        
    </div>
    
</div>
```

Comment: LOL I cant believe I overlooked that! That is embarrassing hahaha Thanks mate :)

Comment: How would I set the main menu item to its "hover" state when I am over the related sub menu??

Comment: your sub menu should be children of the main menu items. OR you can set the hover of the sub menu to trigger the change in the menu items

Comment: Would that have to be done with Javascript or jQuery??

Comment: no. your sub menu just have to be inside the main menu

Comment: Oh! Yeah, I've tried that but it puts everything out of whack. Would I just set the position to below the main menu??

Comment: give your `.sub-menu-wrapper` `position:absolute;` and `top:100%;` and `position:relative;` to your `.menu-item`

Answer (score 2):

Yo have a border on your `<div class="menu">`. So when you move the cursor to the submeny, you hit the border in between and you no longer hover the menu and and therefore the submenu dissapears.

To fix this, add this to your css (remove the border at the botto of your menu):

```
.menu {
    ...
    border: thin solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 0px; /* ADDED */
    ...
}
```

See [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oqjwvv8m/1/)